# HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream returned stream does not send data immediately in .NET Core

Tags: c#

I try to send large files via htpp and have the following code:

```
string filePath = "";
string url = "";
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "PUT";
    request.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    request.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
    request.ContentType = "video/*";
    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
    }
}
```

The expected behaviour ist that as soon as I write data in the dataStream it sends the data over the network. In a .NET Framework app this is the case. I also read somewhere in the docs that this should be the case. In a .NET Core app this is not the case, the data seems to be buffered completely and sending starts not until I call request.GetResponse().

In a. NET Core app I see in the debugger that the returned stream is a RequestStream and I had in Exception where I saw a MemoryStream. In a .NET Framework app the returned stream is ConnectStream...

Can someone reproduce this? Or tell me how I can get a stream in .NET core that sends data out immediately? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an actual bug in .NET Core, in that the value of `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` is ignored and the data is only sent once the request stream is disposed.

See this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18632

The reason it hasn't been fixed in 3 years is that this appears to require a "non-trivial" change, and since `HttpWebRequest` is a legacy API that has been superseded by `HttpClient`, it's pretty low on the priority list.

The recommended solution is to switch over to using `HttpClient`. You're likely to get better performance for comparatively less code, assuming you're okay with using async APIs:

```
// Ideally, create the client once and reuse it
using var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan };

// StreamContent handles content length for you if you give it a seekable stream
// It'll also dispose the stream when it is itself disposed
using var content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open));
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/*");

// send it
using var response = await client.PutAsync(url, content);

// use response
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
// etc.
```

Comment: Nice, thank you for your explanation, I wasn't aware that HttpWebRequest is a legacy API...